# I Want To Set Default System Channel On Discordjs v12

Tags: discord.js

I Want To Set System Channel Messages With Discordjs v12

i tried:
`message.guild.systemChannel.set(channel)`

But It Doesent Work

Answer (score 2):

First you should look for the specific channel like:

```js
const testChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "yourchannelname");
```

and then:

```js
message.guild.systemChannel.set(testChannel)
```

I would do it when client.once is ready or **guildMemberAdd**

Let me remind you that this is working for me in `discord.js 12.5.1` and last version is `13.5.0`

Comment: The find function is not right, you are using the assignment operator (`=`) rather than the comparison operators (`==`, `===`)

Comment: @MrMythical
 You re right ty so much i didnt notice

Comment: it doesent works, it says "TypeError: message.guild.systemChannel.set is not a function"

I Use v12.5.3 Of DiscordJS

Comment: Where are you using it?